# Trying to rotate objects in Pixi.js v 4.6.2

Tags: pixi.js

I'm trying to rotate an object in Pixi.js v 4.6.2 and each time I set the rotation member or call setTransform() the object rotates but also it is moved. I have tried setting the pivot point but that didn't help.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jimarch/4kpuxe8g/)

I have tried:

```
compass.rotation += .5;
```

and:

```
compassContainer.setTransform(0, 0, 1, 1,    0.5,    0,0,  00,00 );
```

and:

```
compassContainer.rotation += 0.5;
```

Here is all the code:

```
var app = new PIXI.Application(400, 400, { antialias: true });
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// Render the compass
var compassContainer = new PIXI.Container();

var compass = new PIXI.Graphics();

compass.beginFill(0xFF3300);
compass.lineStyle(4, 0xffd900, 1);

compass.lineStyle(0);
compass.beginFill(0xFFFF0B, 0.5);
compass.drawCircle(200, 200, 180);
compass.endFill();

compass.lineStyle(0);
compass.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1);
compass.drawCircle(200, 200, 150);
compass.endFill();

compass.lineStyle(4, 0xFF0000, 1);
compass.moveTo(200, 20);
compass.lineTo(200, 40);

compassContainer.addChild(compass);

app.stage.addChild(compassContainer);


// Render the boat
var boat = new PIXI.Graphics();

boat.beginFill(0xFF3300);
boat.lineStyle(4, 0xffd900, 1);

boat.moveTo(200, 100);
boat.lineTo(175, 250);
boat.lineTo(225, 250);
boat.lineTo(200, 100);
boat.endFill();

// Add boat
app.stage.addChild(boat);


// Rotate compass
// compass.rotation += .5;
compassContainer.setTransform(0, 0, 1, 1,    0.5,    0,0,  00,00 );
// compassContainer.rotation = 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got a fixed fiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/themoonrat/cfaq34g7/

```js
'use strict';

var app = new PIXI.Application(400, 400, { antialias: true });
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// Render the compass
var compassContainer = new PIXI.Container();

var compass = new PIXI.Graphics();

compass.beginFill(0xFF3300);
compass.lineStyle(4, 0xffd900, 1);

compass.lineStyle(0);
compass.beginFill(0xFFFF0B, 0.5);
compass.drawCircle(180, 180, 180);
compass.endFill();

compass.lineStyle(0);
compass.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1);
compass.drawCircle(180, 180, 150);
compass.endFill();

compass.lineStyle(4, 0xFF0000, 1);
compass.moveTo(180, 20);
compass.lineTo(180, 40);

compassContainer.addChild(compass);

app.stage.addChild(compassContainer);

// Render the boat
var boat = new PIXI.Graphics();

boat.beginFill(0xFF3300);
boat.lineStyle(4, 0xffd900, 1);

boat.moveTo(200, 100);
boat.lineTo(175, 250);
boat.lineTo(225, 250);
boat.lineTo(200, 100);
boat.endFill();

// Add boat
app.stage.addChild(boat);

compassContainer.position.set( 200, 200 );
compassContainer.pivot.x = compassContainer.width / 2;
compassContainer.pivot.y = compassContainer.height / 2;

app.ticker.add(function(delta) {
  // rotate the container!
  // use delta to create frame-independent transform
  compassContainer.rotation -= 0.01 * delta;
});
```

```css
html, body { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixi.js@7/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Essentially, your positioning of the circle when drawing it, combined with its slightly offset compared to the radius, meant that the centre point was not in the middle of the drawn graphic, and thus the 'wobbling'. In my fiddle, the x and y pos of the drawn circles are now both 180... the same as the radius of the bigger circle

Your first instinct of using pivot was correct, and that fiddle uses that.

Comment: Thanks! Your fiddle still wobbles a bit though. I fixed that by setting compassContainer.pivot.x (and y) to 200, which I assume works because it's parent is the 200 x 200 application. Another question, where does delta come from and what is it? The Pixi docs were not too helpful for Ticker.add().

Comment: Opps... I meant that the parent is 400 x 400.

Comment: The delta is a number... so, by default, the tickers target 60 FPS. This means, if everything is going smoothly, that function will be called every 16ms. And if it is, that delta will be a value of "1". The target time between calls and actual time between calls matches. But if your application was running slowly for some reason, and you were only getting updates every 33ms ( half the amount of time ) that delta value would be 2.

Comment: This is useful for us... because of I wanted to move an object across the screen, I can move it by an amount I want, multiplied by the delta. Now, now matter what the frame rate, after a second of time passing by, that object will have moved the same distance.